# jQuery-ui datepicker method "getDate", when using div as container, returns date even if user hasn't selected anything (should return null)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Update for this issue Aug 4, 2014:

I created bug report with jQuery team, problem acknowledged, a fix won't be created for current version of jQuery UI 1.11.0. Will be fixed as part of rewrite.

See ticket for more information:
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/10465

-- original post below

This will likely fall under the category of "duh that was obvious", but having spent hours trying different things, figured I would ask the collective hive mind.

The jQuery-ui docs for datepicker state that the getDate method will return null if the user has not selected any date from the datepicker.

For some reason I cannot figure out, the "getDate" method is always returning current date (more specifically a Date object set to current date), this makes is difficult to figure out if the user has intentionally selected today's date or not.

I have tried this with many variations of properties including the default .datepicker() object but still same result. Using version 1.11.0 of jQuery-ui.

This actually leads me to suspect another problem I was having is related to this as well, where the class "ui-datepicker-current-day" is being assigned to the default "today" cell when the datepicker is first rendered (which is also incorrect as no current-day has been selected yet)

Thanks

Updated for additional information:

If you use the demo directly from the jQuery-ui docs page, it demonstrates this problem. It appears to be related to using a div as the container for the datepicker (as opposed to an input field).

```
Example http://jsfiddle.net/7GvFn/2/
```

Comment: If possible prepare js fiddle

Comment: If you use the demo directly from the jQuery-ui docs page, it demonstrates this problem. It appears to be related to using a div as a container for the datepicker (as opposed to an input field). http://jsfiddle.net/7GvFn/2/

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you right about one thing

> The jQuery-ui docs for datepicker state that the getDate method will
> return null if the user has not selected any date from the datepicker.

And From [Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate) ,

> #### getDate()
>
> Returns the current date for the datepicker or null if no date has
> been selected.

So i prepared a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/2075/) to demonstrate that it actually does what it is intended.

And apparently setting `defaultDate` too have no effect on result.

Comment: If you use the demo directly from the jQuery-ui docs page, it demonstrates this problem. It appears to be related to using a div as a container for the datepicker (as opposed to an input field). http://jsfiddle.net/7GvFn/2/